# Starcraft 2 license problem on the website

Tags: starcraft-2, battle.net

I have problem my license SC2 license does not show up when I log into my account on battle.net.
The strange thing is that I have it only at website - when I log into my SC2 account in the game everything is fine.
What's going on?

[Here](http://zapodaj.net/dcbeba6fe570.jpg.html) is a screenshot from the website.

Comment: hmm, do you see the screen?
ok if you don't see it the info is just: "xxx, No starcraft2 license found"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as far as i can see from other people on the internet this mostly happens when they go to the wrong region(such as going to [US](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/) instead of [EU](http://eu.battle.net/sc2/en/)), have you made sure that the battle.net page is the one for your region?

This can also happen if you have [multiple starcraft 2 accounts on same email](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2973391595#4), then you need to migrate one or contact blizzard support.

If non of this things are your problem you can try [this](http://us.battle.net/sc2/en/forum/topic/2301730660#4)

> **When I login, I receive the message, "NO STARCRAFT II LICENSE FOUND", and I cannot post.**
>
> Simply try logging in and logging back
>   out. If that does not work, you'll need to flush your account cache.
>   To do this, change something on your account: your password, e-mail,
>   address, etc. Changing anything will reset your account cache.

Comment: Thank's! I was going to US but i have account on EU.